# Building wheel for pyarrow has CMake Error : Target "arrow_python" links to "arrow_shared" but target was not found

Tags: cmake, dockerfile, python-3.9, pyarrow

While doing a Docker build recently, encountered:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
```

Even though I didn't make any changes in the Dockerfile. Build was working fine ~2 weeks ago.
Details of error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:377 (target_link_libraries):
Target "arrow_python" links to:
    Arrow::arrow_shared
    but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:
    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
error: command '/usr/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
```

While searching for solutions in StackOverflow, I tried to specify the CMake version, as well as upgrade setuptools wheel, but still having errors. Appreciate any help on solving this.

======Tried the following suggested by other posts in StackOverflow in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add cmake~3.23.5
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

=====Currently these are in my Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.16

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache build-base \
    autoconf bash cmake bison boost-dev flex libressl-dev zlib-dev

RUN pip install pip --upgrade pip
RUN apk add gcc python3-dev musl-dev libc-dev g++ unixodbc-dev postgresql-dev libevent-dev \
    libffi-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev

ARG ARROW_VERSION=3.0.0
ARG ARROW_SHA1=c1fed962cddfab1966a0e03461376ebb28cf17d3
ARG ARROW_BUILD_TYPE=release

ENV ARROW_HOME=/usr/local \
    PARQUET_HOME=/usr/local

RUN mkdir /arrow \
    && wget -q https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/apache-arrow-${ARROW_VERSION}.tar.gz -O /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz \
    && echo "${ARROW_SHA1} *apache-arrow.tar.gz" | sha1sum /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvf /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz -C /arrow --strip-components 1 \
    && mkdir -p /arrow/cpp/build \
    && cd /arrow/cpp/build \
    && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$ARROW_BUILD_TYPE \
        -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/ssl \
        -DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ARROW_HOME \
        -DARROW_WITH_BZ2=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_ZLIB=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_ZSTD=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_LZ4=ON \
        -DARROW_WITH_SNAPPY=ON \
        -DARROW_PARQUET=ON \
        -DARROW_PYTHON=ON \
        -DARROW_PLASMA=ON \
        -DARROW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        .. \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && cd /arrow/python \
    && python setup.py build_ext --build-type=$ARROW_BUILD_TYPE --with-parquet \
    && python setup.py install \
    && rm -rf /arrow /tmp/apache-arrow.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating FIND_DEBUG_MODE(which is way to noise with the number of dependencies arrow has) shows me that numpy is missing. And indeed installing that prior to the arrow build works.

Additionally you are also missing cython. I would recommend installing the `python/requirements-wheel-build.txt` before the cpp build.

I am unsure how this Dockerfile worked before unless the base image somehow had these installed?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Yes I've installed numpy and cython before pyarrow. But still the same error.

May I know how to install "python/requirements-wheel-build.txt" and what's the content within? Looking forward to your response. Thank you.